# User Access Denied when viewing BIRT Report

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, birt

I have setup BIRT 4.3.2 Web Viewer on Microsoft Server 2012 using Tomcat 8.0.5.  When trying to connect to a database through the BIRT Viewer I get the following Error.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing.
Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Failed to get connection.
SQL error #1:Access denied for user 'webuser'@'10.3.2.50' (using password: YES)
```

I can confirm that I can connect to the db using the Eclipse Designer on the same machine...I also set up a test app on the Tomcat Server that connects and retrieves data from the same db, both using the same credentials.  My driver is placed in the root\webapps\Birt\WEB-INF\lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured a JNDI connection for Tomcat 6.0.39 and I was able to connect to the datasource.  Here are the steps I took:

Install Tomcat [6.0.39[(http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi).

Install the [Birt 4.2.3 Viewer](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/).

Place the WebViewerExample in the $TOMCAT_INSTALL/webapps/ folder and rename the folder to Birt.
Place the JDBC mysql jar in the $TOMCAT_INSTALL/lib/ folder.
Add the following xml to the Birt/WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>[description]</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/MySqlDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Add a context.xml file to BIRT/META-INF/, I had to create the META-INF Folder inside the Birt Project.

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/MySqlDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    maxActive="5" maxIdle="=1" maxWait="10000" username="[username]" 
    password="[password]" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/[dbname]
  </Resource>
</Context>
```

Inside the RPTDesign Edit the Datasource and Include the following JNDI Url:

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/MySqlDB
```

Restart the Tomcat Service and point the to the appropriate URL for the RPTDesign.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your webuser has no access to connect to the database on 10.3.2.50. Please change your credentials to valid ones.

You can verify which credentials are correct using mysql: `mysql -u webuser 10.3.2.50`

Comment: I can connect to the database from 10.3.2.50 via a small app I wrote for the Tomcat Server.